# nodejs - соединение с базой данных

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

Работаю с сокетами, использую sicket.io, express, node.js и ещё нужно подключить mysql.
Скачал плагин mysql  через npm.

Подключил на страницу всё, вот так это всё выглядит:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "admin",
  password: "admin123",
  database: "admin"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1'", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Запрос успешно выполняется, из базы данных пользователя мне показывает.
Но после 10-25 секунд сервер выключается и вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/admin/web/ssd1.had.yt/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/ssd1.had.yt/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/ssd1.had.yt/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Искал в интернете решение, понял что соединение с базой данных надо закрывать.

Добавил вот эту строчку:

`con.end();`

И теперь при закрытие соединения с базой данных у меня выключается сервер, подскажите, может есть какой нибудь вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Ещё раз здравствуйте, разобрался со своей проблемой.
Мне помогло следующее:

1. Я подключил модуль mysql2
   Скачивается он вот так:

   `npm install --save mysql2`
2. Соединение выполняю с помощью плагина pool
   Вот так:

```
 const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'admin',
  database: 'admin',
  password: 'admin123!',
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
});
```

И собственно сам запрос:

```
          $id_db = data.id_bd;
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' +$id_db, function(err, rows) {
             console.log(rows);
             pool.end();

        })
```

Такой способ мне подошел как под версию базы данных 5.7 так и 8+